# AS2: 'If' statement causing perpetual loop

Tags: flash, actionscript, loops, actionscript-2

I am using the following code...

```
var Graphs:Array = new Array(contentMain.graph1, contentMain.graph2, contentMain.graph3, contentMain.graph4, contentMain.graph5, contentMain.graph6, contentMain.graph7, contentMain.graph8, contentMain.graph9);
trace(Graphs);
function dateToString(date:Number) {
    var Days:Array = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    var Months:Array = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    var current_date = new Date(date);
    var day_num = current_date.getDay();
    var year = current_date.getFullYear();
    var month = current_date.getMonth();
    var date_num:String = new String(current_date.getDate());
    date_char = date_num.charAt(date_num.length-1);
    if (date_char == 1) {
        date_suffix = "st";
    } else if (date_char == 2) {
        date_suffix = "nd";
    } else if (date_char == 3) {
        date_suffix = "rd";
    }
    var date_string:String = new String(Days[day_num]+" "+date_num+date_suffix+" of "+Months[month]+" "+year);
    return date_string;
}

var local_data = SharedObject.getLocal("user_data");
Slide_Tracker = local_data.data.user_data;
for (i=0; i<Slide_Tracker.length; i++) {
    var current_date:Date = new Date(Slide_Tracker[i].date_int);
    var date_string:String = dateToString(Slide_Tracker[i].date_int);
    if (i=0) {
        for (s=0; s<Slide_Tracker[i].val_arr.length; s++) {
            Graphs[s].createEmptyMovieClip("chart",10);
            Graphs[s].chart._x = 0;
            Graphs[s].chart._y = 37.9;
        }
    } else if (i>0) {
        var past_date:Date = new Date(Slide_Tracker[i-1].date_int);
        var date_diff:Number = Math.round((current_date-past_date)/86400000);
    }
    for (s=0; s<Slide_Tracker[i].val_arr.length; s++) {

    }
}
```

the problematic code is this:

```
if (i=0) {
            for (s=0; s<Slide_Tracker[i].val_arr.length; s++) {
                Graphs[s].createEmptyMovieClip("chart",10);
                Graphs[s].chart._x = 0;
                Graphs[s].chart._y = 37.9;
            }
```

While this if statement exists (even when empty) it causes a perpetual loop and the "a script is causing this movie to run slow" message to appear.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wanted `if (i==0)` because this just sets `i` to 0 and always returns `true`?

Comment: Yeh... and I knew that but I still didn't see it. :P goddamit cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that "i" will always equal zero as its not being set to anything else, s is the value you are ascending

Inside the if just put:

```
i = 1;
```

or whatever you want to set it to. Alternatively how about

```
if (i==0 && s==0) {
```

(I think thats how you do an 'and' in ActionScript.)

Comment: those are all assignments (=) as opposed to comparisons (==), they won't solve the problem.

Comment: yeah I saw that, I just assumed that was how AS worked since its in a lot of his code...

Comment: i am incrementing the i, the s loop is within the if statement.